# Will a platform device with waiting for supplier eventually probe?

Tags: linux-kernel, drivers, devices, device-tree

I have defined a platform device in the Device tree. The following shows the file tree walk for its folder.

```
/sys/devices/platform/device
/sys/devices/platform/device/uevent
/sys/devices/platform/device/power
/sys/devices/platform/device/power/runtime_active_time
/sys/devices/platform/device/power/runtime_status
/sys/devices/platform/device/power/autosuspend_delay_ms
/sys/devices/platform/device/power/runtime_suspended_time
/sys/devices/platform/device/power/control
/sys/devices/platform/device/driver_override
/sys/devices/platform/device/waiting_for_supplier
/sys/devices/platform/device/modalias
```

In the file `/sys/devices/platform/device/waiting_for_supplier`, There is `0`. I know that if there was `1`, the driver would be waiting for dependencies to be started. After a device successfully probes the file should be automatically deleted.
What causes the file to be there? Could it be that the driver is not compatible with the device? Could it be the driver isn't finding the piece of hardware?